# How to update a double nested value inside an array of multiple documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Imagine the following collection of **city** records:

```
{
  "city": "London",
  "inhabitants": [
    {
      "id": "34543534",
      "user": {
        "name": "Jonathan Deer",
        "email": "john@btinternet.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "0454534",
      "user": {
        "name": "Tanya Patel",
        "email": "tanya@btinternet.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4345345",
      "user": {
        "name": "Catherine King",
        "email": "catherine@gmail.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
{
  "city": "Manchester",
  "inhabitants": [
    {
      "id": "980003",
      "user": {
        "name": "Benjamin Thaw",
        "email": "benny@btinternet.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "734488",
      "user": {
        "name": "Craig Longstone",
        "email": "craig@gmail.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "4400093",
      "user": {
        "name": "Arnold Greentree",
        "email": "arnold@btinternet.com"
      }
    },
  ]
},
```

What I'm trying to do is loop through each **inhabitants** array of each city, and see if any of the people there has an email address containing **btinternet.com** in it. For those users I want to sent a new flag **isBT: true** and for everyone else (e.g., gmail.com users) **isBT: false**:

```
"user": {
  "name": "Tanya Patel",
  "email": "tanya@btinternet.com"
  "isBT" true
}
```

I tried the following queries - first query sets all of them to **isBT: false** while the second one searches for "btinternet.com" in email address and sets **isBT: true**:

```
db.city.update({ "inhabitants.user.email": {$exists: true}}, {$set: { "inhabitants.$.user.isBT": false}}, {multi: true})

db.city.update({ "inhabitants.user.email": {$regex: "btinternet.com"}}, {$set: { "inhabitants.$.user.isBT": true}}, {multi: true})
```

The problem is that when I execute the second query, there are several inhabitants records that are left with **isBT: false** even though they contain the necessary "btinternet.com" email address. It almost seems like only the first user record that matches the criteria gets updated... **Is there a way to update ALL user records for all "*inhabitants*" arrays?**

I looked at using the positional operator $[], but our DB is on version 2.6.3 but this operator was introduced only in 3.6...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no".

The long answer is "no, because your MongoDB version doesn't support such an operation". You'll need to either...
 1. retrieve all matching documents and perform a full array update through server-side processing of the data (e.g. use the MongoDB `cursor.forEach()`),
 2. extend your match for `"inhabitants.user.isBT": true` (use
    `$elemMatch`) and repeatedly perform the update query until the
    number of modified documents is 0 (i.e. there are no more array
    elements to update), or
 3. update your MongoDB version and any
    server-side code that relies on features of the current version that
    have changed between `2.6` and `3.6`.

Any solution to this problem will require more effort than a single query. There's no getting around it. It's a tough pill to swallow, but there really isn't a nice alternative.